# How to change UIImageView frame on UICollectionView cell when the UICollectionView loads?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview, xcode5

MY OBJECTIVE: I need to load an image on the `UICollectionView`, but changing the Y position of it on the `UIImageView` frame, because the loaded image is taller than the cell display window, and I need to display a specific part of it.

SETTINGS: The `UICollectionView` and the `UIImageView` were manually added to the `storyboard (not programmatically)`. The `UIImageView` view mode is set to `Aspect Fill` on the Attributes Inspector.

THE PROBLEM: I've tried changing the `UIImageView` frame after (and also before) loading the image, but the change only takes effect after the `UICollectionView` is scrolled up and down, and I need the image position updated when it first loads.

PS: I've also tried all the different types of view mode on the `UIImageView`, but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Here's the coding I'm using for it:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    PhotoCell *cell = (PhotoCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"PhotoCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.photoImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:_stringImageURL];

    CGRect oldFrame = cell.photoImageView.frame;

    CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(oldFrame.origin.x, -45, oldFrame.size.width, oldFrame.size.height);
    cell.photoImageView.frame = newFrame;

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    return cell;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you reloading the collection view. [collectionView reloadData]; check in you code.

Comment: I've tried it, but the screen gets blank and no image is loaded if I use it on the mentioned delegate method.

Comment: stringImageURL is image name or url of image ? dont use reload in delegate.

Comment: photoImageView , call its clipToBound in PhotoCell call init method.ex-- cell.photoImageView.clipsToBounds=YES;

Comment: stringImageURL is the URL of the image. The clipsToBounds doesn't seem to work.

Comment: how its working [UIImage imageNamed:_stringImageURL]; it should be rather [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:stringImageURL]];

Comment: The image is loading correctly. It's a local file. It's being displayed on the UICollectionView. The problem is the new "Y" position of the UIImageView only updates when the UICollectionView is scrolled, and I wanted it to happen when it first loads.